# In the Ardor API, how can one return more than 100 results from an API call?

Tags: api, ardor

Currently the Ardor API, limits results of 100 at a time. Is there a way to return more than 100 results using the api calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 100 results per API call limit, is a DDOS protection mechanism when connecting to a remote node.

To remove this limitation and allow any API retrieve as many results as possible, do one of the following:

1. Connect to a localhost node.
2. Connect to a remote node and specify the administrator password (adminPassword parameter)

You can learn more about setting the admin password here: https://desk.zoho.eu/portal/jelurida/kb/articles/what-is-the-admin-password

Alternatively, as a node operator you can customize the number of records returned when no password is specified using the nxt.maxAPIRecords property.